# C and Assembly Quiz

Tags: c, loops, assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to understand better how the assembly x86 64 works. And the best way is solving some exercises, I've tried to solve some but now I'm currently stuck understanding this one:

[image]

The main operation here is `addl mat(%rdx, %rcx), %eax`. It's the same as `sum += mat[y][x]`.
By taking a look at the assembly I'm pretty sure that `%rdx` is `x` and `%rcx` is `y`.

So to find out what `MAT_X` is we can see how `y` behaves. And in this case we increment `y` by 172 each end of the first loop until we reach 2924.

This means that `MAT_X = 2924/172 = 17` (Is the reasoning correct ?).
And for the other I would have said `MAT_Y = 10`, since the x loops from 0 to 10 each time.

The solution for this problem that `MAT_X = 17` but `MAT_Y = 172/4 = 43`.

But I don't understand why actually, where I'm I wrong?

Comment: Code must be posted as *text* here, and so should the question itself. Blind users cannot read images. If that means you have to retype it, then so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay calm, you are close. :-)

You can see number 2924 at the end of program. It is the size of the whole array. In other words it's like MAT_X * MAT_Y = 2924. But this value is in bytes! C/C++ languages count everything in variable size, this time it is array of int, i.e. its size is 2924 bytes = 2924/4 = 731 int's.

172 is added at the end of each line, and this number is size of last dimension of the array, i.e. the basis of MAT_Y. But again, it is in bytes in assembler, so you need to count MAT_Y = 172/4 = 43.

Let's verify it:

```
MAT_X = total size / MAT_Y = 731/43 = 17
MAT_X * MAT_Y * 4 = 17*43*4 = 2924
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm a bit confused about the size of the last dimension that you say is 172, because we access mat using y in the first dimension in the code and this confuses me a little bit... We know that in the loop y must be smaller than MAT_Y but we use it to access the first dimension and thus couldn't we actually go out of bouns? Now that I'm thinking about this also this example seems to go out of bounds or not?

Comment: Because we could have `mat[42][x]` but MAT_X = 17

Comment: Good point, you are right. The original C code is not a good quality code. But the asm code provided in the example is really based on that C code. :-)

Comment: All right so we agree on that, thanks again for the answer, will mark it :)